# how to link kal statiac library in my project

Tags: iphone

i am using Kal calender component for my project , I took from

```
     https://github.com/klazuka/Kal
```

I am using xcode4.5 , and confused about step 3& 6

```
       3:   Now you need to link the Kal static library to your project. Select the Kal.xcodeproj file that you just added to the sidebar. Under the "Details" table, you will see libKal.a. Check the checkbox on the far right for this file. This will tell Xcode to link against Kal when building your app.


       6:Finally, we need to tell your project where to find the Kal headers. Open your "Project Settings" and go to the "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search Paths" and double-click it. Add the relative path from your project's directory to the "Kal/src" directory.
```

step 3 is not clear to me in xcode4.5 ,and i am confused about step 6 , should I provide full path ?
please help

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Same problem here